# Deploy RoR to Heroku and Sqlite3 fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've found a number of posts on this same subject ([here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails) one) and thought I made the right changes but I still can't solve the issue.

After completing the bundle install, I push to heroku, I get the following error when it reaches the sqlite3 install.

```
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.5) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for sqlite3.h... no
   sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
   or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
   location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
   Provided configuration options:
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_13nbwv3kitbub/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_13nbwv3kitbub/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:morning-dawn-1372.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:morning-dawn-1372.git'
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'json'

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end 

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer' 

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

it looks like I have both

```
Using sqlite3 (1.3.5)
Using sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
```

on my system. Not sure if this is creatign an issue, but explains why I excluded both in the gemfile.

Environmental info:

```
$ ruby -v 
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i386-cygwin] 

$ rails -v 
Rails 3.2.2
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the `bundle` command and then make sure that both the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are checked into the repo before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: When I run Bundle Install, neither the Gemfile or Gemfile.lock are listed.

Comment: Ok, so I forgot to add the files to the repo before pushing. Problem solved (rookie error), thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You will also get this error if sqlite is specified in your Gemfile without a group- for example

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# below is the line that's giving you trouble    
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.7"
```

Heroku does not allow sqlite in production, so you must either delete this line or change this to something like

```
...
group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.7", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

then do `bundle install`, then `git add` and `git commit` your changes to Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

After you have done this, your `git push heroku master` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Open the Gemfile.lock and scroll down to sqlite3 (1.3.x) under 'specs:'
- Make sure it appears only as sqlite3 (1.3.x) with no extra jazz.
- If any extra tags such as "-x86-mingw32" is displayed then delete it.
- Run Bundle Install.
- Then try pushing Heroku master.

Worked for me.

**Edit**

Now that I know better, please don't ever change the Gemfile.lock manually.
This was written when I started coding in Rails on Windows.
Try updating the particular gem or lock it to a version in your Gemfile.