# heroku sinatra app crashes, error h10

Tags: ruby, heroku, sqlite, sinatra

I am new to heroku and sinatra, but I have my app running locally just fine with sinatra and sqlite3. I know heroku doesn't support sqlite3, so I tried this answer: [Deploy RoR to Heroku and Sqlite3 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857583/deploy-ror-to-heroku-and-sqlite3-fails)

When I pushed to heroku and tried to access it, I got an error. So I checked the logs. This is what I am seeing. I saw others on here with the same issue, but the resolutions have all been varied and I have tried restarting heroku:

```
2013-08-15T05:07:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-08-15T05:07:21.550961+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 28820`
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:23:in `database'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3/lib/sinatra/activerecord.rb:17:in `database='
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339194+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:32:in `spec'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339079+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1191:in `set'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339079+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:55:in `resolve_hash_connection'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1917:in `block (2 levels) in delegate'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339488+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339314+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:2:in `require'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:141:in `start'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
2013-08-15T05:07:25.339770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:250:in `start'
2013-08-15T05:07:27.328918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-15T05:07:27.341978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-15T05:07:28.551518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=intense-depths-3455.herokuapp.com fwd="70.179.10.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-15T05:07:29.149180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-depths-3455.herokuapp.com fwd="70.179.10.147" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

any ideas on how I can get this to work?
my config ru is:

```
#config.ru
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

and my gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem "pony"

group :development do
  gem "shotgun"
  gem "tux"
  gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.3.7", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding a line to use postgresql in production.