# how to use sqlite gem (not DB) on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I need to parse sqlite files on heroku, and as far as i know Heroku does not support sqlite.

In local, i am using the gem sqlite3, but it is rejected when pushing on heroku.
How can i use 'require sqlite3' in production ?

here is the error:

```
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
   Failed to install gems via Bundler.
   Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you just don't want to do that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development

Heroku doesn't support sqlite and you have to use PostgreSQL.  Sorry dude.

This older SO thread has a work around though:

[Deploying RoR app to Heroku with Sqlite3 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails)

The winning answer there was just use sqlite for dev so: (copy pasting)

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately i knew what you said! I do not want to use sqlite as a database (i am using postresql) but i need to parse files (in sqlite format) uploaded by users on heroku. Do you any alternatives to parse sqlite files without using sqlite3 ?

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding your question.  AFAIK you'd have to roll your own (heh or start with the one that sqlite uses: http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/lemon.html)

Comment: @mathieurip did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @RyanAngilly i switched to aws!

Comment: @mathieurip yup i'm moving to Digital Ocean. Oh well. Thanks!