# Heroku push rejected Rails 3.2.8, bundler cannot continue make sure gem install sqlite3 works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm new to rails. I'm trying to push my new rails app to heroku via git but I keep getting the error message: "An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that 'gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6' ' succeeds before bundling.

I checked and I already have the sqlite3 gem. Just to be same I updated the gemfile but this still didn't solve the heroku push problem.
 Also following the tutorial on [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) page, I'm told I have to go to my Gemfile and replace sqlite3 with pg. I don't I should do that because I'm currently using sqlite3 as the application for my database. Will changing to pg solve my problem with heroku? Also will it affect my app or my ability to use sqlite3 any further? Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Heroku supports SQLLite, or didn't last time I checked.  You need to use PostgreSQL.  See this article: [Deploying RoR app to Heroku with Sqlite3 fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that I'm currently using sqlite3 for the database in my rails application

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gemfile with

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

and move the sqlite3 gem into this

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

You'll still be able to use the sqlite DB during development but Heroku will use the PostgreSQL database. Your migrations will make sure the database gets created correctly no matter which database platform you are using.