# Ruby on Rails error with pushing to heroku, sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I have a problem with pushing my app to heroku. It says i have to install sqlite3, but i have installed sqlite! I'm using OSX Mountain Lion

```
>> sudo gem install sqlite3

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7
1 gem installed

>> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 115, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (99/99), done.
Writing objects: 100% (115/115), 33.62 KiB, done.
Total 115 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.11)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.11)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.4)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.11)
       Installing mime-types (1.19)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.11)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.11)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.11)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.7.6)
       Installing rdoc (3.12)
       Installing thor (0.17.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.11)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.2.0)
       Installing pg (0.12.2)
       Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.5)
       Installing rails (3.2.11)
       Installing sass (3.2.5)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
   **strong text**    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1s94inzz103xe/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_1s94inzz103xe/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       **An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.**
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:demoapp1999990.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:demoapp1999990.git'
```

Comment: Can you post your gem file? sqlite should be in dev mode only.

Comment: See the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897431/deploying-ror-app-to-heroku-with-sqlite3-fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't run sqlite on Heroku- try using the postgres `gem pg` instead. Make sure the reference to the sqlite gem is either commented out or in a development only group (`group :development do . . .end`) in the gemfile. Then add the gem for postgres (`gem pg`). Then do `bundle install --without development` and try the push again

Comment: At the very least, you will need to add a dev database in order to take advantage of Heroku Postgres: https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/