# Heroku gemfile error when trying to open and edit my site locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite, gemfile

I am building a site using Heroku using a tutorial in my online class. I keep getting this error when attempting to open it locally:

```
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library

gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'pg'
end
```

This is the full gem::LoadError:

```
require path_to_adapter
rescue Gem::LoadError => e
raise Gem::LoadError, "Specified '#{spec[:adapter]}' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem '#{e.name}'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)."
rescue LoadError => e
raise LoadError, "Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.", e.backtrace
          end
```

Comment: You can't use SQLite on Heroku. See https://simonecarletti.com/blog/2016/01/post-heroku-sqlite/ https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app http://stackoverflow.com/a/3897593/123527

Answer (score 0):

Switch to Postgresql. SQLite is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle install` locally and then push to Heroku