# Rails 3 - can't install pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql-9.1, pg, libpq

When I try to run bundle (bundle install), I all the time get

```
Installing pg (0.13.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I use Mac OS X 10.6, the version of installed PostgreSQL is 9.1. I found the problem is in the **libpq-dev**, how could I install/fix that?

Comment: how have you install postgres on your mac ?

Comment: [this](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) way

Comment: on_click installer ? Flink ? or MacPort ?

Comment: I tried to install that by this way: `sudo port install libpq-dev`, but another problem - `Error: Port libpq-dev not found
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>`. That's terrible, still some problems...

Comment: See this question:

[here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321189/teaching-myself-rails-deploying-first-app-to-heroku-failure-to-upload-sqlite3

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As stated in your error log you need to pass in the path to the pg_config. Try to install the gem using:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= 'PATH_TO_YOUR_PG_CONFIG'
```

If you are not sure where your pg_config is, and assuming you are on Linux or Mac, you can run the following command:

```
which pg_config
```

Your pg-config can be in different locations depending on how you installed postgres.

Comment: As a note, the binary package from the Postgres site does not contain development headers or the `pg_config` program.

Comment: The binary package from here: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx most certainly *does* contain both `pg_config` (e.g., at `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config` for 9.1.x) and the development headers. It's what I use to test the `pg` gem in development.

Comment: Wouldn't `which pg_config` be faster than `find / -name pg_config`?

Comment: Made a minor tweak to your command line args. Replacing the version with your current one should work ok. Here's my command line:

    sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-include=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/include/ --with-pg-lib=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/

Comment: On OSX you may also use brew to get the headers via `brew install libpqxx` and everything will go fine.

Comment: For some reason `which` did not find the location of the `pg_config` file. for me it was located at `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config`. just in case this may help someone else

Comment: Mine was `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_config`

Comment: If you're using the POSTGRES app from Heroku, the pg_config is located at /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config

Comment: You can change this to: `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=\`which pg_config\``

Answer (score 100):

if you are running on Linux you may be interested in what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then

```
gem install pg
```

then

```
bundle install
```

src: http://wikimatze.de/installing-postgresql-gem-under-ubuntu-and-mac

Comment: thank, as it's in my case - no need to run bundle gem install pg

Comment: Worked for me as of November 2013 running Ubuntu 13.04!

Comment: why does this have so many upvotes when it's clearly for the wrong OS?

Comment: @sevenseacat it clearly states the OS it should be used on. And clearly a lot of people with Linux OSes are finding this answer when they research this problem.

Comment: This should work if you use the repositories. Obviously it won't work if you compile from source. But it worked beautifully on Ubuntu 14.04 when using the repositories.

Comment: That made it work. Key point being that postgresql needs to be installed on your machine.

Answer (score 58):

If you're using [Postgress.app](http://postgresapp.com/) then youll want access to its [command-line tools](http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html). Enter the following line in your terminal or your [PATH profile](http://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac-os-x/):

```
 PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

`gem install pg` should now work. (This is what worked for me.)

**Note** New versions path looks like:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/<version>/bin
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent half an hour going through things that did not work and finally found this buried down here. :D

Comment: Great solution that doesn't require brew.

Comment: Just be aware that the Postgre.app patch changed in the 93 version. it is now: /Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin

Comment: This worked for me, though my bin was in a very different place -> /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin

Comment: Postgres.app explains the updated path to use in this documentation page: http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Comment: This is now - `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin` as of 9.3.5 if you are using the Postgres.app

Answer (score 22):

If you have homebrew, just type:

> $ brew install postgresql

If you dont have it, download typing this in your terminal:

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

Answer (score 12):

Search for libpq:

```
brew search libpq
```

Should output `libpqxx`

Then try install it:

```
brew install libpqxx
```

Answer (score 8):

You only need to install `libpq-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then the gem should install just fine.

Comment: In my case only this helped. Thanx!

Answer (score 7):

Follow the post-installation instructions: http://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-ruby.html

To install the pg gem, make sure you have set up your $PATH correctly (as specified in http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html), then run

`sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

I **strongly** recommend reading both pages. Just skimmed them and lost 1 hour of my life. Read them, problem solved.

Comment: Works on OSX 10.9.5, default ruby version 2.0, rbenv local version 1.9.3.

Comment: Works on OSX 10.11 THANKS

Comment: Works on OSX 10.11.4. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem I had was that for some reason it was trying to compile with /usr/bin/gcc-4.2.  I found that out by changing try_cpp in mkmf.rb (which I saw in the stack trace) to raise an exception with the compile line that was failing.

I soft-linked gcc to gcc-4.2 and it worked:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Why was it trying to use gcc-4.2? No idea.

The actual compile line:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -E -I/Users/dfrankow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.4.0 -I/Users/dfrankow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/dfrankow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/include  -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c -o conftest.i (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue but my Postgres was install in

`/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3`

Updated the ~/.bash_profile by adding:

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin:$PATH
```

Open a new terminal, run `bundle update` and also it worked for me. Thanks Ari.

Comment: but for me to work need to check the version then export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 1):

You can set a build config option `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config` and use `gem install pg` without any options (the path to pg_config may be different for you, this one is for the Postgresapp 9.3.5.0)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my openSUSE13.1 KDE machine. Before that issue I encountered I had installed only the packages `postgresql` and `postgresql-server` using `zypper` command. Then installed again 2 more packages :

```
[arup@to_do_app]$ sudo zypper in postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib
root's password:
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...
#....
```

Then, I ran again `bundle install`, and success!!!

Answer (score 0):

For a working OSX solution see this guide http://krugerdavid.com/journal/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-postgresql-ruby-1-9-3-on-snow-leopard/

It will walk you through installing PostgreSQL using homebrew. Tested and working for me on OSX 10.8.3, PostgreSQL 9.2.3, and Ruby 2.0.0-p0

Answer (score 0):

First, uninstall any Homebrew versions. The --force option makes it uninstall all versions.

```
brew rm postgresql --force
```

Change paths accordingly for your version.

```
sudo /sbin/SystemStarter stop postgresql-8.4
sudo rm -rf /Applications/PostgreSQL\ 8.4
sudo rm -rf /etc/postgres-reg.ini
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/postgresql-8.4
sudo rm -rf /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4
sudo dscl . delete /users/postgres
```

Edit /etc/profile and delete any lines that reference "postgres".

```
nano /etc/profile
```

Install PostgresSQL

```
brew update
brew install postgresql
```

Install de PG GEM

```
gem install pg
```

That's it. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check to see if you have a postrgresql file in your terminal by going to lib file. going  cd ~/opt/local/lib/ and then type ls and the enter button. This will show you a list of all the files that are located in the lib directory.

1.if you dont have postreseql you can download through macports.
sudo port install postgresql93 @9.3.2_1

Now cd back into your folder which you are trying to bundle install

1. getting your pg to work with your postgesql file you have or just downloaded 
   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql93/bin/pg_config

now run
bundle install

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora:

```
dnf install postgresql-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on El Capitan was upgrading ruby from the system default to 2.3.1 seemed to find the correct libraries that the `pg` gem needed.