# teaching myself rails deploying first app to heroku -failure to upload - sqlite3 and postgre glitch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org, gemfile

Im teaching myself rails. Im a programmer but not a web programmer. Im going through Michael Hartl's book [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

It mentions that its a good idea to start deploying your app right from the beginning. I agree. So I got an account on Heroku and went through ther setup etc. Then created my 1st app, git and the works. Then followed all the instructions on Heroku's site. Finally I came to pushing my app up to Heroku using this command:

```
git push heroku master
```

The book says that there could be problems at this stage because the app on my machine is using sqlite3 while Heroku wants postgresql. 
The book suggests changing a line in the gem file of my app from

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :group => :development
```

I tried that and then ran bundle install and then tried to push the app. No luck
I get this message on my console:

```
An error occured while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

!
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

So I tried what the Heroku website suggests [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

to change my gemfile

from this:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to this:

```
gem 'pg'
```

so I tried this approach and then ran 'bundle install'. But that didn't work either. I get this message on my console:

```
Installing pg (0.13.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2     for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing pg (0.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Tried to run this command:

```
gem install pg
```

that failed with the following error message:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/AM/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2     for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/pg-0.13.2/ext/gem_make.out
```

Can someone please help me with this. ive hit a roadblock. Not sure what to do next.Thanks

Comment: Search on Google : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668753/rails-3-cant-install-pg-gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what worked:
1) Install postgresql on the machine

2) For permanent fix - Go to the .bash_rc file and add the following: 
    export PATH = "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/":$PATH
OR
just to install the missing files and run the bundle command one time type this in the root of the app:
    PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/ bundle install
or
    PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/ gem install pg

3) Now the pg gem is installed

This post was helpful:
http://excid3.com/blog/installing-postgresql-and-pg-gem-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 5):

The right configuration in your case has already been posted in other answers and I attach it here for your convenience.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

However, keep in mind that when you run `bundle install`, bundler will try to install all gems for all environments. Later, it will load only the gems for the specified environment at runtime.

This is the reason why on your local machine it is trying to install `pg` as well.

You have two possibilities to solve the compilation error:

1. Install `libpq`, the library required by the `pg` gem to compile. You don't need to install the full PostgreSQL client or stack, `libpq` is enough to pass compilation. On MacOSX you might want to install it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
2. Tell bundler to skip unnecessary groups when running install.

   ```
    bundle install --without production
   ```

As a side note, please keep in mind that SQLite and PostgreSQL are two different databases. It's always a good idea to use a development environment as similar as possible to the production one. My personal suggestion is to install PostgreSQL on your local machine and use it both on development and production.

Again, homebrew is your friend.

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to install Postgres locally. It appears that you're on a Mac, so the easiest way would be to use the installer here:

http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

Then stick with this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: I would like to just use pg for production and deployment. Since thats what Heroku recommends. Is there a way to get pg to work ?
Thanks

Comment: I haven't yet found a reason to want to use pg for development. sqlite seems to the job just fine where performance isn't key.

Comment: I see. I was confused because Heroku says this: "We highly recommend using PostgreSQL during development. Maintaining parity between your development and deployment environments prevents difficult to diagnose bugs introduced by subtle differences between your environments."------And so I wanted to be careful as I begin my app. I wouldn't want to write the thing and then have a problem during deployment. So are you suggesting use sqlite3 for development and use pg for production and that should cause no bugs.

Comment: I haven't found any issues yet, and I've deployed a number of apps to heroku, though the theory of keeping things the same is sound.

Comment: There's a good video walktrhugh of installing postgres on the mac: http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-install-and-use-postgres-on-os-x-for-ruby-and-rails-development-4999.html

Comment: OK thanks. I'll stick with trying to get pg running for the sake of simplicity, especially while Im new

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the error that the pg is not installed on your system, so you can not install the gem.

Although heroku not advised to use a different database, I have worked like this:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```