# Installing pg gem on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundle

I'm developing a rails app using sqlite3. I want to push it to Heroku. In Heroku tutorial it says that I have to first change:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

to

```
gem 'pg'
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

I got this error:

```
 Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions 
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ...
 Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
 *** extconf.rb failed ***
 Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
 details.  You may need configuration options.
 ...
```

next I tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668753/rails-3-cant-install-pg-gem):

```
 running gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= /usr/bin/pg_config
```

I also tried running:

```
 sudo apt-get install postgresql
 sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

and

```
 gem install pg
```

works fine..

But

```
 bundle install
```

still gives me the same error

Note: I'm using rvm

Comment: I think the fact that I'm using rvm is somehow making things complicated so none of the solutions on SO works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

in your gemfile so that you can use sqlite in development and when you push to heroku as production it will be pg.

Comment: yes tried this. and then 'bundle install'.. still getting the same error

Comment: @shane: Did you specify a `--without` option? E.g., `bundle install --without=production`?

Comment: I did. This way the 'bundle install' goes well but then when I want to push it to heroku... I still get:

         updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
         You have added to the Gemfile:
         * pg
         You have deleted from the Gemfile:
         * sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

Change your gemfile to the following:

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'pg', :group => :production
```

This way you will use SQL locally in development. Heroku will ignore the sqlite gem, and use Postgres instead.

Comment: This is a way to do it.  But it doesn't address the problem of not being able to install postgresql locally.  The user should be able to so that if they wish.

Comment: You are correct, but I don't think that is his request.  

"I'm developing a rails app using sqlite3. I want to push it to Heroku."

It is common practice to develop with sql and push to heroku with pg. Heroku's instructions to move to dev work to postgres can be ignored.

Comment: sure, I just want to make sure the OP knows the difference (=