# "bundle update" failed to install pg (0.14.1) with native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran `bundle update` (so that I can install rails), but got this error:

```
$ bundle update
..... < other stuff ....>
Installing pg (0.14.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I'm new to `Ruby` and all this, could anyone tell me what is wrong here?
This is on OSX

Comment: It is important to know what OS you are running here.

Comment: This is OSX(, as the path `/Users/user/...` should have suggested)

Comment: It looks like you're missing postgres-dev files and have a gem in your gem file that needs it.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure ton install postgres first. I suggest you do so via [homebrew](https://brew.sh), the Mac package manager.

```
brew install postgresql
```

[Here is one](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/) of the many tutorials on how-to install postgres on a Mac.

**EDIT**

Looks like the gem can't find your postgres config, here's an answer similar to your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669523/277370

Comment: `postgres` as in `posgresSQL`? I do have PSQL on my machine, if that is what you're asking?

Comment: are you able to run psql or createuser commands in your terminal?

Comment: Well, I have the PSQL interface (to talk to other database server, not necessarily the PSQL server). And `psql` is in my path. So I can type `psql` fromt the terminal without getting `command not found`

Comment: Ok, so I found the `pg_config` file (in `/usr/local/pgsql-9.1/bin/`, and ran `gem install pg -- ...`, that should resolve the problem? ANything else I should try?

Comment: Just make sure to accept this answer if it was of any help, that's about it.

Comment: Yes, your answer and the answers in the link help. Thanks.