# 'Could not find pg-0.12.2 in any of the sources' when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems, pg

I'm working on building the twitter clone app in Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I cloned my git repo (https://github.com/stewartmccoy/rails_tutorial) and put code on to my personal computer, which had previously been on my work computer. So, my developer environment might be slightly different than what's specified in my Gemfile.

My environment:
Mac OS 10.6.8
Rails 3.2.13
ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- actionmailer (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- addressable (2.3.2)
- annotate (2.5.0)
- arel (3.0.2)
- bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
- bigdecimal (1.1.0)
- bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0)
- bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.6)
- builder (3.0.4)
- bundler (1.3.4)
- capybara (2.0.2, 1.1.2)
- childprocess (0.3.9, 0.3.6)
- coffee-rails (3.2.2)
- coffee-script (2.2.0)
- coffee-script-source (1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.4.0)
- cucumber (1.2.1)
- cucumber-rails (1.2.1)
- database_cleaner (0.7.0)
- diff-lcs (1.2.1, 1.1.3)
- erubis (2.7.0)
- execjs (1.4.0)
- factory_girl (4.1.0)
- factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
- faker (1.0.1)
- ffi (1.4.0, 1.3.1)
- gherkin (2.11.5)
- hike (1.2.1)
- i18n (0.6.1)
- io-console (0.3)
- journey (1.0.4)
- jquery-rails (2.2.1, 2.1.4, 2.0.2)
- json (1.7.7, 1.7.6, 1.7.5, 1.5.5)
- libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)
- mail (2.5.3, 2.4.4)
- mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
- minitest (2.5.1)
- multi_json (1.7.1, 1.5.0)
- nokogiri (1.5.8, 1.5.7, 1.5.6)
- pg (0.14.1)
- polyglot (0.3.3)
- rack (1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.1)
- rack-cache (1.2)
- rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
- rack-test (0.6.2)
- rails (3.2.13, 3.2.1)
- railties (3.2.13, 3.2.11, 3.2.1)
- rake (10.0.3, 0.9.2.2)
- rdoc (3.12.2, 3.12, 3.9.5)
- rspec-core (2.13.1)
- rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
- rspec-mocks (2.13.0)
- rspec-rails (2.13.0)
- rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)
- rvm (1.11.3.6)
- sass (3.2.7, 3.2.4)
- sass-rails (3.2.6, 3.2.5)
- selenium-webdriver (2.31.0, 2.27.2)
- sprockets (2.2.2, 2.1.3)
- sqlite3 (1.3.7)
- thor (0.17.0, 0.16.0, 0.14.6)
- tilt (1.3.6, 1.3.3)
- treetop (1.4.12)
- tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.35)
- uglifier (1.3.0)
- websocket (1.0.7, 1.0.6)
- will_paginate (3.0.3)
- xpath (1.0.0, 0.1.4)

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'  
  # gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  # gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Anyway, I'm trying to run the test just after Listing 8.18 (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-reviewing_form_submission):

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
```

And I get this error:

```
Could not find pg-0.12.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So, I run `bundle install` and and get this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.4) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.2.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.11) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.12) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using activeresource (3.2.11) 
Using addressable (2.3.2) 
Using annotate (2.5.0) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0) 
Using will_paginate (3.0.3) 
Using bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.6) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.6) 
Using ffi (1.3.1) 
Using childprocess (0.3.6) 
Using websocket (1.0.6) 
Using libwebsocket (0.1.7.1) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.9) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.27.2) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.4.0) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.6) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.11) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using gherkin (2.11.5) 
Using cucumber (1.2.1) 
Using cucumber-rails (1.2.1) 
Using database_cleaner (0.7.0) 
Using factory_girl (4.1.0) 
Using factory_girl_rails (4.1.0) 
Using faker (1.0.1) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Installing pg (0.12.2) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.12.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.12.2/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.12.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Finally, I tried `PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin sudo gem install pg` and got:

```
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/stewartmccoy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.15.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Suggestions?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check what adapters you have on config/database.yml. Probably you have setup the postgres or pg adapter with the **test** environment.

However, on your Gemfile, you have setup postgres just for production:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

if you add the test environment and run **bundle** again, it should work:

```
group :test, :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Also see the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9669523):

Try to install the gem with this command:

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= 'PATH_TO_YOUR_PG_CONFIG'
```

If you don't know where your pg_config is, run this command:

```
which pg_config
```

BTW, did you already install postgres on your desktop? All you need is the postgres development package to install the gem.

Comment: ah. I just checked my database.yml file and all the adapters are set for sqlite3. I'll need to fix that. Strange because I thought I'd already set production to postgres.

Comment: btw, I just checked your answer one more time, and you are actually having troubles with the installation of postgres, could you let me know your operating system?

Comment: I updated Gemfile: 

`group :test, :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end`

and also database.yml:

`production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: rails_tutorial
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

but still get: 

`Could not find pg-0.12.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.`

Comment: Sure thing. My environment was listed at top of post, but here it is again: Mac OS 10.6.8 Rails 3.2.13 ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

Comment: ok, you will need to install postgres, you can install it automatically with brew or port, otherwise you can download the source code but that will be a little harder than using brew.