# bundle install error on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Im a newbie please help....Im getting the below message..

Can someone tell me what the below message means and provide me with a steps by step on how to fixed..

PS: I've installed `homebrew`, `postgresql` and `xcode`, but still have this problem when i Run bundle install..

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:970:in `block in find_header'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:969:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:48:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-10/1.9.1-static/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Can you paste `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-10/1.9.1-static/pg-0.17.1/mkmf.log`

Comment: You have installed postgresql, but have you installed the developer extensions for postgres? If you are on debian linux, can you paste the output of 'dpkg -l | grep postgresql' or similar for your distro

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668753/rails-3-cant-install-pg-gem

Comment: Hi all , fixed with the following

Comment: if any one the same problem as above just follow http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#code-create_gemrc  follow from chapter 1.2 ( up and running ) to chapter 1.2.4 bundler..